# C++ Passing to a function turns object variables into junk

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an object to my function, but when I do the values I need get changed somehow. 
I start out by creating the mesh object in the Model constructor

```
Model::Model(GameObject &gameObject, Renderer &r, string const &path, uint &mCount, uint &tCount) : renderer(r), meshCounter(mCount), textureCounter(tCount), Component(gameObject) {
    loadModel(path);
    cout << "Model indicesSize: " << meshes[0].indicesSize << endl;
    r.testThing(meshes[0]);

    r.createCommandBuffersModel(meshes.data(), meshes.size(), buffers);
}
```

where `loadModel()` creates a vector of Mesh objects and assigns it to the class member `meshes`
The specific variable I'm having trouble with is an `uint32_t` called `indicesSize` that stores the size of a vector called indices

When I call `cout` on that variable it gives me "7248" which is what it should be. However, when I then call `r.testThing(meshes[0])` defined as

```
void Renderer::testThing(const Mesh mesh) {
    cout << "Test function indicesSize: " << mesh.indicesSize << endl;
}
```

it gives me a number like 18242600 `(uint 0x0adf9990)`. This number changes every time, but is usually around 17 or 18 million. Additionally, according to the visual studio compiler other things about the `mesh` object are junk, for example the `indices` vector of uints is now of size `0x3f2da854` and is filled with junk, mostly 0s.

This is about the simplest I can distill the problem. Nothing else in my program is having any trouble of this sort, and this problem only appeared after I switched from header only to header and source files.

I originally had a vector of meshes passed by value to the function `createCommandBuffersModel`, but I moved to function `testThing` for simplicitys sake. I tried many different ways of passing, including a vector of meshes passed by reference, a vector of pointers, an array of meshes, a mesh pointer, a mesh reference, and just a mesh. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anyone with a similar issue, and I didn't even really know what to search for.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community. I'm interfacing with the Lunar Vulkan SDK, although that should have no baring on my current issue. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information, this is my first question on this site so this may not be perfect.

Mesh class: https://github.com/henry-arjet/VKTest/blob/master/Include/arjet/mesh.h

Comment: What is "meshes", it's not in the code snipped you posted. When you print/read values and they change on every run, that is often an indicator for uninitialized variables.

Comment: Sorry meant to post the mesh class. And I would agree, I just don't understand why it's initialized in the Model constructor but uninitialized when it's passed into the testThing function.

Comment: Ah, no I didn't mean the class definition. You use a vector/an array called "meshes". Where is that declared? Is that a member of the Model class? I don't see you initialize that in the constructor, so where do you do that?

Comment: What I said in the question was "where `loadModel()` creates a vector of Mesh objects and assigns it to the class member `meshes` "
The actual definition is `vector<Mesh> meshes;` in the class Model

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Could you show that initialization code please? Also, you don't need to have a variable 'indicesSize' - you should keep all your data private and then you can simply add a public `indicesSize()` method to your Mesh class, which just calls `indices.size()`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, I'm still kinda jankily making my way through this program. I used to have it as just calling indices.size() but that wasn't working for some reason that I no longer remember. 
The initialization for the mesh is almost the entirety of [model.cpp](https://github.com/henry-arjet/VKTest/blob/master/model.cpp) and the init function of [mesh.cpp](https://github.com/henry-arjet/VKTest/blob/master/mesh.cpp). The declaration for the meshes vector is just vector<Mesh>meshes.
The gist of it is I create a mesh then push_back onto meshes

Comment: I'm sorry, but that code is a bit of a mess. model.h is all commented out, but there is obj_model.h, but you are not including that in model.cpp

Comment: Oh I know it. The include chain gets to obj_model.h, it just doesn't go there directly. I would not describe this project as following best practices, so I really appreciate you taking time to look through my spaghetti. I just don't understand how meshes[0].indicesSize could be different numbers directly before and after its passed to a function.

Comment: That makes it harder to keep track of things... Anyway, bc. of this mess, it's hard to say where the original error happens. I don't want to setup Vulcan on my machine to try it out. But one thing i notice is, that you pass around lots of things by-value, which could explain what you see: Maybe the objects in meshes aren't initialized properly and when you call testThing() it makes a copy of your mesh, which is a new object which isn't properly initialized. So you see different values. Since Mesh looks like a big, expensive object, I'd pass it by reference.

Comment: Also, two-phase-construction (constructor + init()) is an anti-pattern. Either use a constructor (and you can call a function there, like in the "learnopengl" folder you have) or you can hide your constructor and make factory function.

Comment: You could try and create a Minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without any of the Opengl/vulkan stuff - Only a Model class with a vector of Meshes and a testThing function. Delete everything not needed to reproduce the bug. Then I could test it, otherwise I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I ended up burning my project down and restarting it in a more ordered fashion, copy/pasting a lot of my original code. I encountered a similar bug which I ended up tracing to trying to push_back(&Constructor()) instead of push_back(new Constructor()). But I don't think that was my original issue. Either way, it works now. Meine Deutsch ist nicht sehr gut, aber ich werde probieren. Danke fuer alle Seine Hilfe. Es war meine zuersten Frage an StackOverflow, und ich werde immer sich errenen, vie hilflich Sie waren.